# select dictionary item with min value in array of dictionary elements in python 2.7

Tags: python, list, dictionary, min

I have an array of dictionary elements like this:

```
d = [{'k': 'k1', 'v':4}, {'k': 'k2', 'v':5}, {'k': 'k3', 'v':2}]
```

I would like to retrieve a value of 'k' from the the dictionary element with lowest 'v', there may be more than one with the same lowest value.  In the case of the example above, I would like to get:

```
['k3']
```

This is what what I have so far, is this the most efficient and pythonic way of solving the problem (besides collapsing the two lines into one)?

```
m = min([x['v'] for x in d])                               
r = [x['k'] for x in d if x['v'] == m]
```

Thanks.

Comment: `k3` is not one of your keys.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear - I edited to be more exact

Answer (score 2):

Remove the unnecessary list comprehension and use a generator expression instead.

```
m = min(x['v'] for x in d)                               
r = [x['k'] for x in d if x['v'] == m]
```

---

But is there a reason you are keeping a list of key-value pairs, rather than a `dict`? (To have a multimap?)

```
d = {'k1':4, 'k2':5, 'k3':2}
m = min(d.itervalues())                        
r = [k for k, v in d.iteritems() if v == m]
```

Comment: The list of dictionaries is what I am given to work with form another part of the system, I would like to just retrieve a value of 'k' from the the dictionary element with lowest 'v', there may be more than one with the same lowest value.

Comment: @IUnknown, if possible, if `d` is meant simply to be a list of keys and values, I would recommended changing that part of the system (if possible) to use a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

```
r = min(d, key=lambda x: x["v"])["k"]
```

This should give you 'k3'